# Covered Box Beamer Shadows

Tags: beamer, boxes, transparency

It seems to me that in beamer, a (rounded) box with shadows that is covered (transparent, normally visible on the next slide) has buggy shadows, I'm not sure if this is a know bug, or maybe an error on my part.

My minimal code is the following

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\uncover<2>{
\begin{block}{Head}
Body
\end{block}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

As you can see, the shadow seems to be above the box.
It looks like this both in Acrobat Pro, Reader, and on Ubuntu.

Any ideas how I can get rid of it?

Comment: It looks fine in Mac OS Preview. Either it's a viewer-specific problem, or you should make sure that your LaTeX distribution is up to date.

Comment: I'm running `pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)` on Ubuntu/Lucid with evince 2.30.3 and it looks fine to me, as Jubobs suggested maybe you're running an older version?

Comment: It was indeed a version issue, only beamer version 3.18 installed on this computer I am using at the moment. With beamer 3.26 everything works fine, Thanks.

Comment: On that basis, 'too localized'.